# Can I call functions using Mirrors in Swift

Tags: swift, reflection

I create a mirror in Swift using `mirror: Mirror(reflecting: self)`. Can I use this `mirror` variable to call any function in `self` i.e. current class. If yes, how? if no, what are other reflection ways to solve it in Swift